# How to move the ball in parabola shape with angling the ball in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

Iam new to andengine. I wish to make a game which about football how to angle the ball in different directions and move it in an parabolic shape, i badly need an answer from any of you developers.

Thanks in advance if any one responds to my query.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to use the box2d physics engine plugin to do that, check out tutorials for using that and you should be able to do so

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I have been using box2d physics engine itself i have created a ball and the ball also moving in different directions when i click on it, i used accelerometer class for this behaviour but the ball is not in a position of steady when the app started it is moving in different directions i need the ball to be steady in position and when i clicked on it ,it should move in what ever direction user prescribes the ball and it should not come back again when it colloides with any other object. 
Please paste the source code link if anyone have.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of movement can be expressed as a two numbers 
This vector can be converted into an angle. 
Rotate your graphics to that angle.

Code example:

```
public Double rotateTowards(x1:Float, y1:Float) {
    var radianAngle:Number = Math.atan2(x1, y1);
    return radianAngle * 57.2957795;
}
```

This function returns the angle the football should rotate to face while moving in the x and y directions given. It will work with negative values as well. The code gives the rotation in radians. So you have to multiply it by 57.2957795 to convert it to degrees used by andengine's setRotation();

1 radians = 57.2957795 degrees

It is possible that your football may be rotating 90 degrees from the intended angle. If that is the case just add or subtract 90 to the value returned.

Do you still need help with the parabola or do you have that handled with box2D?

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Can i have any example source code project.